# How do i get onto a Samba share on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, 64-bit, samba

I have setup a Samba share that i have hosted with my RPi (RPi 3B+) and used my Lenovo computer with MX Linux 32-bit 
setup:

- RPi 3B+ with proper power supply
- Lenovo computer MX Linux 32-bit
- Everyone else uses Windows 10
  So i fully setup my Samba server all up and running, I could get onto it, but then I tried on a computer using Windows 10, I was on the same network, and we went onto network, nothing showed so we typed in:
  smb://HostPiLocal.local/ ***Which is the official local server name***
  and then Windows said:
  You will need to download something to open 'SMB' shares

So we did that and nothing is there, I did a bit of configuration and still nothing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the message you received.

Answer (score 1):

Try \\HostPiLocal.local\ in Windows explorer address bar

Comment: Resolving a share or local hostname address on Windows via `hostname.localdomain` generally requires the configuration of three things: **(1)** Server must be assigned a static IP on the router; **(2)** Windows' `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` must have an entry within it for the server in the following format: `<IPaddress>  <Hostname>  <Hostname.LocalDomain>` **(3)** Windows' Workgroup name must be set to the `localdomain` name.  Without these three things, Windows, nor the router, knows where to route the request.

Comment: this can be also handled by running a DNS server at the router, then adding an entry to HostPiLocal.local with its static IP. [example](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp.dnsmasq)